# error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-11.1.so qemu-virgil on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shared-libraries, ubuntu-18.04, virtualization, qemu

How to fix this ? (on ubuntu 18.04 for arm64 on jetson nano and I can't upgrade ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 because nvidia does not support 20.04 at the moment)

```
root@ziomario-desktop:# uname -a

Linux ziomario-desktop 4.9.140 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 8 00:07:34 CET 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux


root@ziomario-desktop:# sudo snap install qemu-virgil

error: snap "qemu-virgil" is not available on stable but is available to

install on the following channels:


edge snap install --edge qemu-virgil


Please be mindful pre-release channels may include features not

completely tested or implemented. Get more information with 'snap info

qemu-virgil'.


root@ziomario-desktop:# snap install --edge qemu-virgil

2021-02-14T13:09:37+01:00 INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...

qemu-virgil (edge) 4.2.0 from Oliver Grawert (ogra) installed


root@ziomario-desktop:# sudo snap connect qemu-virgil:kvm

root@ziomario-desktop:# qemu-virgil

/snap/qemu-virgil/62/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-11.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: I suspect snap makes this more complicated, but just to check: do you have the package which provides the libpulsecommon library installed ? It ought to be in the 'libpulse0' package.

Comment: I have installed these packages already : libpulse0 ; libpulse0:armhf  ; libpulse-dev ; libpulse-dev:armhf ; pulseaudio ; pulseaudio:armhf. but the error still there.